# How to use dot as in punctuation and not append in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm putting a SQL query together in PHP. How do I declare a dot in punctuation?

Example code as requested:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE LOWER(location2) REGEXP '.* .$location .*'";
```

See `.*` is a regexp and should not be interpreted by PHP as a concatenation.

Comment: even here the . stars are not showing up

Comment: @Kevster This is a simple syntax problem.  Break up the problem to determine where your syntax error is.

Comment: Voted to move to Stack Overflow, which is aimed at programming questions such as this.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE LOWER(location2) REGEXP '.*London.*'   The stars are not showing before london and after the dot but my problem is Im getting a count of all the rows and WHERE is not working

Comment: Let's not migrate this. Follow the DMC rule - Don't Migrate Crap. This question shows little knowledge about what is going on.

Comment: No the code was correct but you are right I was programmig so much in javascript that I started adding "+" to my php code

Comment: As written the query would be "...WHERE LOWER(location2) REGEXP '.* .london .*'"; Thus is obviously wrong. $vars inside double quotes are expanded, inside single they are not..

Comment: @duncan you might have a wacky dmc rule, i dont appreciate being RAMmed so I use DDR "Dont Dipsh** Reality"

Comment: Cervantes or Shakespeare I forget said "Better to be a witty fool than a foolish wit" so don't try it buster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with PHP syntax.  Your example contains a `.` inside a quoted string, which PHP interprets as a `.` inside a quoted string.  Therefore nothing is wrong there.

What you're probably experiencing is MySQL treating the `.` as a wild-card operator in a regular expression.  In regular expression syntax (whether in MySQL, PHP, Perl, wherever) `.` is a wild-card that matches any single character.  If you want to include a literal `.` in your regex, you need to escape it, i.e. `\.`.

Because you are using it inside a string inside a string, you also need to escape the `\` character so that it makes it through to the regex correctly.  Without testing I would say it needs escaping twice (once for PHP and once for MySQL), e.g. `"'\\\\.'"` in PHP becomes `'\\.'` in MySQL, becomes `\.` in the regular expression.

(Obviously, only escape the `.` characters that are meant to be treated literally - I would assume the `.*` is meant to match any character - these should not be changed.)

Comment: REGEXP '.* .london .*' would match (zero or more any characters)(space)(any character)(london)(space)(zero or more any characters)  Highly unlikely to be found.

Comment: Depends what the data looks like.  Also, there is no assumption here that the regex is correct for the OP's purpose - the question was about why the `.` character wasn't working as expected.  My interpretation is that the `.` before location is intended to be a literal period, not a wildcard.